# Integrating asp.net webforms and mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am developing an asp.net mvc website product that needs to allow customers to add their own content pages, outside of the project.

So the product will deliver a core set of pages (views) all using a master page.  The clients can add their own web pages (.aspx) which I was hoping they could inherit from the MVC masterpage.  Obviously there is no view context, so all of my html helpers, and Url.* calls fail.

What would be the best strategy to allow someone to add web pages into an mvc product, re-using as much of the structure as possible.

Comment: Can the client add an arbitrary number of pages?  Or is there a set number of pages they are allowed to edit?

Comment: They can add as many as they want.  The sitemap xml file will allow them to integrate these into the site seamlessly.

Answer (score 2):

What you are describing is a Content Management System.  There are a number of those available for MVC.  One of them is N2.  N2 is a lightweight CMS framework to help you build web sites that anyone can update:

http://n2cms.com/

Another one is Oxite.  Oxite is a pure MVC CMS:

http://www.codeplex.com/oxite

These are open-source, so you can break them open and see how they did it.

Answer (score 0):

Scott Hanselman's blog post on how to mix together these technologies is required reading for anyone wanting to use ASP.NET MVC and classic ASP.NET together.

[Plug-In Hybrids: ASP.NET WebForms and ASP.MVC and ASP.NET Dynamic Data Side By Side](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/PlugInHybridsASPNETWebFormsAndASPMVCAndASPNETDynamicDataSideBySide.aspx)

Comment: Yes, but this is more side-by-side not integration.  I want to be able to use my MVC masterpage html from my web forms.